# Chunk Length from ChunkedZIP Response is not correct

Tags: c#, gzip

So what i'm doing is:

```
int blockLength;
try {
    blockLength = Convert.ToInt32(line, 16);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException) {
        throw new Exception("WrongChunkedBlockLength", ex);
    }
    throw;
}
if (blockLength == 0) {
    yield break;
}
```

(where line = a line read from the stream that is expected to be the chunk length)
This works fine but for whatever reason im getting returned a value thats lower than what the actual chunk size is. What I mean by this, is im sending a request to Hotels.com and when I get the "chunk size" and then read from the stream with the chunk size as the length/count it reads it all, but theres actually still further data to read for that chunk.
Since the code now thinks it read the full chunk, it loops to continue the next chunk only to get hit with first chunks data.

This is how im reading from the stream:

```
int totalBytesRead = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[blockLength];
while (totalBytesRead < blockLength) {
    int read = stream.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, blockLength);
    if (read == 0) {
        WaitData();
        continue;
    }
    totalBytesRead += read;
}
```

and then right after that this is what I do to further test the issue:

```
buffer = new byte[90];
while (true) {
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10);
    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
}
```

Comment: http 1.0 is stream mode and 1.1 is chunk mode.  Chunk mode requires you to send Next Chunk message to get more data.  If you do not send the next chunk message you will get a timeout error.  I've never gotten 1.1 to work in the Net library because I've never found a way to send the next chunk request.

Comment: @jdweng ? im using 1.1 and im getting all chunk data just the chunk length is wrong. Im not getting timeouts

Comment: For example it returns 24576 as block length (when converted to int32(16)) yet theres still tons more data available in the stream BEFORE the next chunk int message shows

Comment: Why do you care if you are getting all the data.  What is the final status?  Are you getting 200 Done?

Comment: @jdweng Im retrieving the body... I need all the data of the body...

Comment: You can't just get a piece of the download and expect the byte count of the response to be accurate.  You are not explaining yourself very well.

Comment: its basically doing this:
12 (pretend this is hexadecimal cba to convert)\r\n
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

As you can see, there's 20 a's in this chunk, yes its telling me 12 is the chunk length...

Btw I did get a "solution" to this but its not ideal. Im essentially getting the chunk count and using it more as a buffer rather than a length count. So lets say it returns 12, I will keep reading 12 until returns that it read nothing, I then check if the total bytes read = chunk length if so it re-loops and gets next chunk length. (1-continued)

Comment: This caused an issue though, since at times the buffer read would be LESS than the chunk length, I had to basically just Array.Resize so that it only keep from 0->ReadCount that way null bytes (0x00) at the end of the buffer wouldnt be yield returned. Of course I could probably just utilize offset with the totalBytesRead count but literally dont want to touch the code, it works, not great, but it works. (2-end)